# How to remove just the numeric data to fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have data that will be entered into a table, and right now it comes as [68.0,00.2].  I want to lose the [ ] at the front and end, and no comma, put the numeric info into different fields.  When I try something like what I have below:

```
Select SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', 2,CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')-2) as cpu_01,
SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')+1, 
(LEN('[68.0,00.0]')-1)) as cpu_02
```

I get:
    cpu_01  cpu_02
    68.0    00.2]

Why can I not get rid of that last ] ??

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend the method you're using to split a string, but to answer your specific question of why you get the bracket:

The final parameter of SUBSTRING() is length, you're treating it as if it were the ending position.

> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
>
> length Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how
>   many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is
>   negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If
>   the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters
>   in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is
>   returned.

This would work:

```
Select SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', 2,CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')-2) as cpu_01,
SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')+1,
(LEN('[68.0,00.0]')-CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]'))-1) as cpu_02
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` for this type of operation:

```
select left(v1.str, charindex(',', v1.str) - 1),
       stuff(v1.str, 1, charindex(',', v1.str), '')
from (values ('[68.0,00.2]')) v(str) cross apply
     (values (replace(replace(v.str, '[', ''), ']', ''))) v1(str);
```

This first gets rid of the `'['` and `']'`.  Then it uses string manipulations to split the value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are - with 1 if you use this :

```
Select SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', 2,CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')-2) as cpu_01,
SUBSTRING('[68.0,00.2]', CHARINDEX(',','[68.0,00.2]')+1, 
(LEN('[68.0,00.2]')-7)) as cpu_02
```

You will see the result which you need.

```
 LEN('[68.0,00.2]) =11
```

So If you add -7 you will get true answer.
result :
cpu_01  cpu_02
68.0    00.2